# How to call ActiveRecord::Base's load-method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

To do a special kind of validation in an ActiveRecord-based model I need to manually do the update_attributes-steps:
load(params) && save

But when I try to call "load" on my Model's instance (mymodel.load(params)) it calls "load" on ActiveSupport, trying to load a file.

Is there a way to tell Rails to use the ActiveRecord-method?

Thanks!

Regards
Marc

Comment: Can you outline what you're trying to accomplish? Generally speaking, if you're fighting the framework, you're "doing it wrong"

Comment: It's about an event: You aren't allowed to change it if it's in the past. But a simple validation doesn't work, you can just change the dates to dates in the future. So I have to check the parameters. As this feels like fighting the framework, I want Rails to parse the parameters and check the object itself. By overriding update_attributes I also can abort the save if something goes wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want the `assign_attribute` method of `ActiveRecord::Base`.

I'm using Rails 3.1.3, but hopefully this is correct for you.

The `update_attributes` source you pasted belongs to `ActiveResource::Base`, not to`ActiveRecord::Base`.  I just made that mistake myself: [Is it possible to call ActiveResource::Base#load?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8439173/is-it-possible-to-call-activeresourcebaseload) `ActiveRecord::Base` does not supply a `load` method. Instead the `load` method of `Object` is called, which appears to be supplied by ActiveSupport's `Loadable` module in `activesupport-3.1.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb`.

Answer (score 1):

Straight from the source:

```
# File activerecord/lib/active_record/base.rb, line 2665
def update_attributes(attributes)
  self.attributes = attributes
  save
end
```

Actually it's rails 2, but I imagine it didn't change all that much.

Comment: Oh, right, I've forgot to tell that I'm using Rails 3. The source has changed according to api-dock: `# File activeresource/lib/active_resource/base.rb, line 1267
    def update_attributes(attributes)
      load(attributes) && save
    end`