# Is it possible to call ActiveResource::Base#load?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

The `ActiveResource::Base#update_attributes` method calls a `ActiveResource::Base#load` method which is defined in `activeresource-3.1.3/lib/active_resource/base.rb` (line 1255). I am trying to call that `load` method, rather than simply using `update_attributes` so that the object is not saved immediately.

1. I tested this with a completely new rails application. I scaffolded a simple object:

   ```
   rails scaffold obj property1:string
   ```
2. Then in the rails console:

   ```
   irb(main):001:0> obj=Obj.new
   irb(main):002:0> obj.load(:property1=>"data")
   TypeError: can't convert Hash into String
   from .../activesupport-3.1.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:234:in `load'
   from .../activesupport-3.1.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:234:in `load'
   from .../activesupport-3.1.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:223:in `load_dependency'
   from .../activesupport-3.1.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:640:in `new_constants_in'
   from .../activesupport-3.1.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:223:in `load_dependency'
   from .../activesupport-3.1.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:234:in `load'
   from (irb):2
   ```

I see that `activesupport-3.1.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb` applies its `Loadable` module to `Object`, giving every object a `load` method for loading files, but I can't figure out why it overrides the `ActiveResource::Base#load` method and not the other way around.

I am using Rails 3.1.3 and friends.

### Update:

I think I've answered my own question. I've been trying to use ActiveResource methods on ActiveRecord objects. I know that my Rails model classes are descendants of `ActiveRecord::Base`, but somehow when I was trying to find the code for `ActiveRecord::Base#update_attributes` I found the code for `ActiveResource::Base#update_attributes` instead, which looks like this:

```
def update_attributes(attributes)
  load(attributes, false) && save
end
```

So I've been trying to call the `load` method, which exists for my objects only as provided by activesupport. If I had only looked at `ActiveRecord::Base#update_attributes` which is

```
def update_attributes(attributes, options = {})
  # The following transaction covers any possible database side-effects of the
  # attributes assignment. For example, setting the IDs of a child collection.
  with_transaction_returning_status do
    self.assign_attributes(attributes, options)
    save
  end
end
```

I would have seen that the `assign_attributes` method is what I needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of doing that, you could use .attributes

```
obj = Obj.new
obj.attributes = { :property1 => "data" }
```

The instance has new attributes, but has not been saved.

Read the [Docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html#method-i-attributes-3D) for more info.

Comment: Thanks, that would work for my test case above, but I need something that will eventually handle complex data like nested-parameters.

Comment: On further inspection, I see that `obj.assign_attributes` and `obj.attributes=` actually handle nested parameters the same in Rails 3.1.3. The only differences now (Rails 3.2.1) have to do with security roles.